# Api for getting BLE Scan result using Bluetooth Scanning Always Available even when bluetooth is off

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

We know since Android 6, we have an option in Android under Advanced Wifi settings which says "Bluetooth Scanning always on". It says it scans for Ble devices even when bluetooth is off. 
We have the same option for Wifi also that is "Wifi Scanning Always Available". If it is on, we can get the wifi scan results programmatically in the Scan Callback after calling the startScan method. 
Is there any way to get the Ble Scan Results, the devices scanned even when bluetooth is turned off in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Though you are right in expecting BleScans when the bluetooth is turned off as the device is still receiving probes from the nearby BLE devices, unfortunately android doesn't provide any BLE Scan Result when bluetooth is turned off.